# SUM value from 2 lists

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following outputs:

```json
 {
    "vmoff": [
        {
            "CONT2": [
                "vm1",
                "vm2",
                "vm5"
            ]
        },
        {
            "CONT1": [
                "vm3",
                "vm4",
                "vm6"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

AND

```json
{
    "vmprof2": [
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "0.5",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.5",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.5"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "1.0",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.7",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.7"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sum the value of proc of each vm in vmoff, for example:

```yaml
proc_steal:
  - sec_sys: CONT1
    proc: 2.0
  - sec_sys: CONT2
    proc: 2.2
```

Obtain the proc of the not activated vm, I'm getting confused on the output, don't know to use list or dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a custom filter:

Create a folder `filter_plugins` at the same level as your playbook.

I created a file `myfilter.py` with a filter named `extractfilter`

```
.
├── filter_plugins
│   └── myfilter.py
└── playbook.yml
```

whith the following content:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'extractfilter': self.extractfilter
        }
 
    def extractfilter(self, l1, l2):
        result = []
        ky = {}
        for k in l1:
            ky.update(k)

        for k in l2:
            s = k['sec_sys']
            l = ky[s]
            if s in ky:
                total = 0.0
                proc = k['proc']
                for p in proc:
                    if p in l:
                        total = total + float(proc[p])
                result.append({'sec_sys': s, 'proc': total})

        return result
```

Then the playbook which uses the custom filter:

```yaml
- name: testplaybook jinja2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    vmoff:
      - CONT2:
        - vm1
        - vm2
        - vm5
      - CONT1:
        - vm3
        - vm4
        - vm6
    vmprof2:
      - proc:
          vm1: '0.5'
          vm2: '0.7'
          vm3: '1.0'
          vm4: '0.5'
          vm5: '0.5'
          vm6: '0.5'
        sec_sys: CONT1
      - proc:
          vm1: '1.0'
          vm2: '0.7'
          vm3: '1.0'
          vm4: '0.7'
          vm5: '0.5'
          vm6: '0.7'
        sec_sys: CONT2
  tasks:

    - name: DEFINE VARIABLE SPINE
      set_fact: 
        proc_steal: "{{ vmoff | extractfilter(vmprof2) }}"
 
    - debug: msg="{{  proc_steal }}"
```

result:

```json
{
    "msg": [
        {
            "proc": 2.0,
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": 2.2,
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you have a problem with the custom filter you could use jinja:

```yaml
- name: "make this working"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vmoff:
      - CONT2:
        - vm1
        - vm2
        - vm5
      - CONT1:
        - vm3
        - vm4
        - vm6
    vmprof2:
      - proc:
          vm1: '0.5'
          vm2: '0.7'
          vm3: '1.0'
          vm4: '0.5'
          vm5: '0.5'
          vm6: '0.5'
        sec_sys: CONT1
      - proc:
          vm1: '1.0'
          vm2: '0.7'
          vm3: '1.0'
          vm4: '0.7'
          vm5: '0.5'
          vm6: '0.7'
        sec_sys: CONT2
  tasks:
    - name: list to dict
      set_fact: 
        ky: "{{ ky | d({}) | combine( item ) }}"
      loop: "{{ vmoff }}"

    - name: list to dict
      set_fact: 
        result: "{{ result| d([]) + [{'sec_sys': s, 'proc': total}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vmprof2 }}"
      vars:
        s: "{{ item['sec_sys'] }}"      
        l: "{{ ky[s] }}"
        total: >-
            {%- set st = namespace(tt=0.0) -%}
            {%- for p in item['proc'] if p in l -%}
            {%- set st.tt = st.tt + (item['proc'][p] | float) -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
            {{ st.tt | float }}  
      when: s in ky
      
    - name: list to dict
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy for the respond, i tried in my laptop, and it work. But i tried in a server, it shown the following error: "template error while templating string: no filter named 'extractfilter'. String: {{ vmoff | extractfilter(vmprof)}}". Ansible core = 2.12.1, python version = 3.8.6

Comment: Are you sure to have respected all names (folder  and right  content  of program python) there  is no reason to not see the filter

Comment: the differences is that where im implemeting is Anisble Tower,  i put the plugin in a role format. I create the dir filter_plugins in tasks and change the permisison to awx. @Frenchy

Comment: i dunno why you have a problem, so to avoid custom filter you could use jinja see my answer modified...

Comment: thanks, it works